# Assign an image to jQuery Object Data that can be filtered

Tags: jquery, object, filter, slider

I have a bunch of object data corresponding to different Beer types, there are 3 sliders that a user can adjust, if these align to the object data I want that image to be displayed in the div below.

```
    <label for="slider-step">Colour:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-step" id="slider-step" value="20" min="0" max="40" step="10" />

    <label for="slider-step">IBU:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-step" id="slider-step" value="60" min="50" max="70" step="5" />

    <label for="slider-step">ABV:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-step" id="slider-step" value="6" min="2" max="10" step="2" />


    <div class="showImage">
        Image Appears Here
    </div>
```

Here is a jsFiddle with the variable data: http://jsfiddle.net/54AqX/

Comment: what is the question? define "align to data" since you have 5 objects and 3 sliders. WHat image? Too many unknowns without a better explanation.

Comment: Sorry very vague. Difficult to explain: When the slider points relate to points assigned to the object data I want an image to be displayed.
Each object would have its own image. I didn't supply an image in the jsFiddle as I wasn't sure where it would be in the html.

Comment: you need to completely update question with full details of exaactly what you are trying to do including connecting data to html shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to create an object through which you can iterate every time any of the sliders changes. However, there has to be a chance for any of the beers to fall in the ranges you have set; because of that I had to lower the IBU minimum from 50 to 30.

The following code should do the sensing for every change:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').on('input',function() {
        var output = $('div.showImage');
        output.empty();
        var color = $('#color').val(),
            ibu = $('#ibu').val(),
            abv = $('#abv').val();
        console.log(color,ibu,abv);
        $.each(beer, function(k,v) {
            !(v.color[0] <= color && color <= v.color[1]) ||
            !(v.ibu[0] <= ibu && ibu <= v.ibu[1]) ||
            !(v.abv[0] <= abv && abv <= v.ibu[1]) ||
            output.append( k );
        });
    });
});
```

The following demo shows the changes I made to create the object:

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/54AqX/3/)

Comment: That is perfect! How would I change the output to an image as opposed to the beer title?

Comment: In the object for each beer define the image URL for that beer. Then change output.append( k ) to output.append( '<img src="' + v.imageURL + '"/>' )

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again. One last question; If I wanted to add a description for each beer that also pops up beside the image. Would this be done using spans also assigned to each object?

Comment: Yes, it would make sense to do it that way.

Comment: Would you be able to update the jsFiddle for an example - as soon as I do it stops working :(

Comment: [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/54AqX/7/) is an updated demo for you. Is that close enough?